# Azure web job and tfs builds

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-webjobs

I have a console app (Azure web job) project and a empty web app project in a solution of many projects.

I want to be able to deploy the web job using a tfs online build. Currently I have a post build script to copy the bin dir from the web job to app_data/jobs/triggered/webJobName in the empty web app project. This is not the best solution for many reasons.

I would rather have a build that deploys the web job directly, or have tfs copy the latest build files and deploy. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

The built in azure template will only deploy one, the primary, project.

If you switch to the TfvcTemplate.12.xaml you will get two folders in _PublishedWebApplications. One for each app.

You can then create post-test PowerShell that does the deployment and call It from the but in post test activity.